# Other uses of App ID in iOS App

Tags: ios, app-id

I understand that App ID is used to uniquely identify an iOS app. Am I right?

Apart from this, are there any other user case where the App ID would be referred/used?

E.g: Would App ID be used for say in some part of the push notification work flow, or say in generation of an provisioning profile or in any other process of developing an iOS app or specific iOS functionality?

I was asked this questing during an iOS interview and am curious to know the answer.

Comment: You use it for deep linking too!